# Program stops during threading

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

So, I'm writing a program for class that runs 4 threads concurrently. I've got the program working perfectly, except for the fact that it's stopping during run-time. I'm not sure if it's related to the way I have my pthread_cond_wait's set up, or if its something else. I've traced through the program by hand multiple times, and can't find an explanation. 
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//#define TENP .1
//#define FIFTP .15

void *tenPercentA();
void *tenPercentB();
void *fiftPercentC();
void *fiftPercentD();

pthread_cond_t aPirate;
pthread_cond_t bPirate;
pthread_cond_t cPirate;
pthread_cond_t dPirate;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int pearls = 1000;

int main()
{
        pthread_t tid;

        pthread_setconcurrency(4);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void *(*)(void *))tenPercentA, NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void *(*)(void *))tenPercentB, NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void *(*)(void *))fiftPercentC, NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void *(*)(void *))fiftPercentD, NULL);

        pthread_exit(0);
}

void *tenPercentA(){
        int totalA = 0;
        double tempA = 0;

        while(pearls > 0){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                if(pearls > 0){
                        tempA = pearls * .1;
                        tempA = ceil(tempA);
                        totalA = totalA + tempA;
                        pearls = pearls - tempA;
                        printf("Pirate A stole %1.1f pearls.\n", tempA);
                        printf("Pirate A's total: %d\n", totalA);
                        sleep(1);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&bPirate);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&cPirate);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&dPirate);
                        tempA = 0.0;
                }
                else{
                        printf("No more pearls!\n");
                        exit(0);
                }
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                pthread_cond_wait (&aPirate, &mutex);
        }
}

void *tenPercentB(){
        int totalB = 0;
        double tempB = 0;

        while(pearls > 0){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                if(pearls > 0){
                        tempB = pearls * .1;
                        tempB = ceil(tempB);
                        totalB = totalB + tempB;
                        pearls = pearls - tempB;
                        printf("Pirate B stole %1.1f pearls.\n", tempB);
                        printf("Pirate B's total: %d\n", totalB);
                        sleep(1);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&aPirate);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&cPirate);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&dPirate);
                        tempB = 0.0;
                }
                else{
                        printf("No more pearls!\n");
                        exit(0);
                }
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                pthread_cond_wait (&bPirate, &mutex);
        }
}


void *fiftPercentC(){
        int totalC = 0;
        double tempC = 0;

        while(pearls > 0){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                if(pearls > 0){
                        tempC = pearls * .15;
                        tempC = ceil(tempC);
                        totalC = totalC + tempC;
                        pearls = pearls - tempC;
                        printf("Pirate C stole %1.1f pearls.\n", tempC);
                        printf("Pirate C's total: %d\n", totalC);
                        sleep(1);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&bPirate);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&aPirate);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&dPirate);
                        tempC = 0.0;
                }
                else{
                        printf("No more pearls!\n");
                        exit(0);
                }
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                pthread_cond_wait (&cPirate, &mutex);
        }

}

void *fiftPercentD(){
        int totalD = 0;
        double tempD = 0;

        while(pearls > 0){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                if(pearls > 0){
                        tempD = pearls * .15;
                        tempD = ceil(tempD);
                        totalD = totalD + tempD;
                        pearls = pearls - tempD;
                        printf("Pirate D stole %1.1f pearls.\n", tempD);
                        printf("Pirate D's total: %d\n", totalD);
                        sleep(1);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&bPirate);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&cPirate);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast (&aPirate);
                        tempD = 0.0;
                }
                else{
                        printf("No more pearls!\n");
                        exit(0);
                }
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                pthread_cond_wait (&dPirate, &mutex);
        }

}
```

And here's some sample output that it does during run-time:

```
Pirate A stole 100.0 pearls.
Pirate A's total: 100
Pirate B stole 90.0 pearls.
Pirate B's total: 90
Pirate C stole 122.0 pearls.
Pirate C's total: 122
```

The only idea I have that might explain it is that the program is getting stuck when the CPU scheduler has two threads ready to run back to back. For example (in the schedule queue): A | B | C | C | D. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not necessarily related, but you may want to check your docs on [pthread_cond_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html). I see you're unlocking the mutex immediately prior to the wait, which is redundant. the wait will unlock it for you. Likewise, on return from pthread_cond_wait, the mutex is locked, making your relock immediately after also redundant. I suggest you review your pthreads book (or maybe I need to, cause its been awhile).

Comment: "I've got the program working perfectly, except for the fact that it's stopping during run-time" - that doesn't sound perfect...

Comment: now that I look at it, it doesn't matter anyway, since I see no pthread_cond_init even *creating* those condition variables, so its not like any of those waits are going to work anyway.

Comment: The condition init's are at the top of the program. pthread_cond_t <variable name> creates a wait condition.

Comment: @Baelix Like I said, its been awhile, because when *I* learned pthreads, you had to initialize *every* pthread artifact; condition variables were no exception, requiring [pthread_cond_init](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_init.html) to properly set them up. Are you saying that is no longer the case and simply *declaring* them is sufficient? And if so, *since when*??

Comment: My understanding of it is yes, that is correct. The pthread library takes care of initializing the variables for me. At least, that's what I've gathered from my professor, and the docs I've read on pthread

Comment: You may need to have words with your professor then, because up-to-and-including the latest POSIX pthread spec I've seen (2003), not sure if there are any newer, initialization of *every* pthread object (mutex, cond-var, etc) is *mandetory*. The POSIX spec-page for pthread_cond_init [is here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_cond_init.txt) and makes no mention of it being optional. I'm curious to know how many of your pthread_mutex and pthread_cond_ functions are returning EINVAL. perhaps you may want to check the return results of those calls and not ignore them.

Comment: From the doc I've been reading: "Variables of type pthread_cond_t can also be initialized statically, using the constant PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER. In the Pthreads-w32 implementation, an application should still call pthread_cond_destroy at some point to ensure that any resources consumed by the condition variable are released." Which makes me think that either way is correct.

Comment: You most certainly can use PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, which is also not in the code above. `pthread_cond_t aPirate;` has no initializer assignment that I can see. Unless this isn't your actual code base. Likewise with PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER.

Comment: What I meant by that was, you can either use pthread_cond_t OR use pthread_cond_int to statically initialize it. In either case, I'm not receiving any errors along those lines, not to mention I have a full working program (different assignment) using those same calls, which works just fine :/

Comment: Well good for small miracles, because i just downloaded the above source, compiled it, and the very first pthread_mutex_lock call fails with err 22 (EINVAL), precisely what it is supposed to return if the mutex object is not valid. Just declaring them isn't enough; they need to be initialized, one way or another. These aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while(pearls > 0){
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     if(pearls > 0){
          <do some stuff>

     } else {
           print "all done";
     }                
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
     pthread_cond_wait (&bPirate, &mutex);
 }
```

So if all the pirates wait at pthread_condition_wait then when the last pirate steals the last pearls you *might* find that pearls  == 0 and exit the loop. Now you'll never print your all done condition. And you'll exit without anything being printed by falling off the end of the program.

That's why your program is stopping and not printing anything.

Edit: (the above is still true, but isn't the problem you are seeing at the moment)
From http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait:

> They shall be called with mutex locked by the calling thread or undefined behavior results
>
> These functions atomically release mutex
>
> Upon successful return, the mutex shall have been locked and shall be owned by the calling thread

```
So what you want is:
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (pearls > 0) {
    <do your thing>
    <signal other threads>
    pthread_cond_wait(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: But my program is printing out data. It's just stopping mid execution, for a reason that I can't quite gather. I've listed some sample output above, and where it stops the program has paused for some reason. The only thing I can think of is that the scheduler has put two threads in queue for execution back to back, and since I only release the wait on all 3 other threads, I think that may be why its pausing. But I have no way to confirm this.

Comment: So it hangs but doesn't exit? Because you said it exits .... so that's the behaviour I was trying to explain.

Comment: "except for the fact that it's stopping during run-time." It's pausing, not exiting the program. Sorry, I should've made that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems in your program.

**1.- pthread_cond_wait without lock**: like dave already pointed out, you should call it with mutex locked. Otherwise you have undefined behavior (which is always bad).

Example:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (!conditionMet) {
  //..
  pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

**2.- Access to non-mutex-protected variable**: you are accessing the variable `pearls` in your threads without protecting the access with the mutex (in `while(pearls>0)`). Another thread may be writing to it. Although it is probable that the access is atomic, it is not guaranteed.

**3.- exit(0) inside the threads**. exit() causes normal program termination to occur. It guess, this is not what you want inside your thread function. Just use `return` to exit the thread.

**4.- pthread_exit(0); in main().**  pthread_exit() function terminates the calling thread. At the end of main, you should wait for all threads to terminate first. Use `pthread_join` for that (you will need one `pthread_t` for each thread). Then return normally to exit the program.

You should fix all these things first before searching further.